# Substring in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have string "10-1283-01" the length going to be same  , i want to check is that string like "10-xxxx-0x"
only want first 3 character like "10-" and last but one two character  like "-0".

So I am diving/Substring something like below. for first3 its giving me required string but for lastPart its giving me ArgumentOutOfRangeException.

Please let me know how i will get -0 string? Thanks in Advance

```
  string partnoveri = lpartno.Text;
    string first3=partnoveri.Substring(0, 3);
    string lastPart = partnoveri.Substring(partnoveri.IndexOf("-0"),partnoveri.Length-1);
```

Comment: if ((partnoveri.Substring(0,3)=="10-"&&(partnoveri .substring(7,2)=="-0")) then valid else not valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why dont you use regular expression?

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            var pattern = "[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}";
            var input = "10-1283-01";

            var matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
            if(Regex.IsMatch(input, pattern))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("MATCH");
            }



        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }




}
```

Comment: The OP gave a criterion for which the regex pattern would be "^10-[0-9]{4}-0[0-9]$" (assuming the `x` is intended to be [0-9]).

Comment: my fault. I'm sure he can figure it out. hopefully, he'll invest some time and learn regex.

Comment: @KMC thanks for your help. that's work great for me, in my coding i need to add some more patterns like "15-xxxxx-0x","800-xxxxx-0x" etc. so I am trying to understand who write var pattern. I am using https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650303.aspx . Any advice where i get clear idea of Regex Pattern. I dont have much time to go in details right now.

Comment: You can learn regex expressions from here. Give it a try and if you're really stuck then reply and I'll give you some help. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @KMC...I got it. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The C# [Substring](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx) method is not

```
String.Substring( int startIndex, int endIndex )
```

as your code suggests, rather it is

```
String.Substring( int startIndex [, int numberofCharacters ] )
```

Given that, if you're looking for two characters, you'd use:

```
string lastPart = partnoveri.Substring(partnoveri.IndexOf("-0"), 2);
```

That being said, I'd opt for @KMC's regular expression solution. While `Substring` will work in the case of your example, it will fail if the fourth character is zero, as in 10-0283-01

Answer (score 1):

Just reading about [Ranges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/ranges) introduces in C# 8.0 spec.

Reading this question:

> I have string "10-1283-01" the length going to be same , i want to
> check is that string like "10-xxxx-0x" only want first 3 character
> like "10-" and last but one two character like "-0"."

one can do (since c# 8.0 specs):

```
string partno = "10-1283-01";
Console.WriteLine($"{partno[0..3]}");    // returns "10-"
Console.WriteLine($"{partno[^3..^1]}");  // returns "-0"
```

Answer (score 0):

To receive two last characters you can use substring like below:

partnoveri.Substring(partnoveri.Length-2, 2);

You can also use Regular Expression for this case.